# Delete Trigger causing issues with FK on delete set Null and causing ORA-03113

Tags: triggers, foreign-keys, constraints, oracle12c

FK on Table -

```
ALTER TABLE APP.BC_CUSTOM_SI_PROPERTIES ADD (  
  CONSTRAINT BC_SI_PROPS_CUSTOM_ATTR_FK 
    FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTER_ID) 
     REFERENCES APP.BC_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTERS (CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTER_ID)
      ON DELETE SET NULL
       DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
        ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Trigger on BC_CUSTOM_SI_PROPERTIES -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APP.BC_ACS_SI_CUST_PROPERTY
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF SI_PROPERTY_ID,PROPERTY_NAME
ON app.bc_custom_si_properties  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.INPUT_TYPE_CC=3 OR OLD.INPUT_TYPE_CC=3)
DECLARE
l_object_id app.bc_acs_obj_change_tracking.object_id%TYPE;
l_object_type app.bc_acs_obj_change_tracking.object_type%TYPE ;
l_owner app.bc_acs_obj_change_tracking.object_id2%TYPE;

BEGIN
   IF NOT app.utils_Pkg.workspace_dup_del_running_p = 1 THEN -- 
      IF SYS_CONTEXT('clus_ctx','import_in_progress') IS NULL THEN
         IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
             l_object_id := :new.si_property_id;
             l_owner := :new.owner;
         ELSIF DELETING THEN
             l_object_id := :old.si_property_id;
             l_owner := :old.owner;
         END IF;

         l_object_type := 'SI_PROPERTY_ID';

         IF app.bc_acs_pkg.ws_access_policies_enabled_p (l_owner) = 1 THEN
            app.bc_acs_pkg.populate_obj_change_tracking
                (p_object_type => l_object_type,
                 p_object_id   => l_object_id,
                 p_object_id2  => l_owner,
                 p_object_id2_type => 'WORKSPACE'
                );
         END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;

END ;
/
```

When Trying to delete CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTER_ID from the BC_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTERS from toad, getting 
ORA-03113  end of file on communication channel.

Initially I was facing the issue on another set of table where I had Compound Trigger and I was thinking it is compound trigger that is causing issue. 
But then I checked other cases where even the normal delete trigger is causing the issue.

Has anyone seen such issue and know the workaround.

Comment: @Belayer  can you help here

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production